# GROUP BY two columns and return a third column values based on condition in SQL

Tags: sql, date, group-by

I have some data consisting of a date_time, job_name and status column. The jobs can be run once per day or multiple times per day at different moments and they result in a status which is either "success", "failed" or "disabled".

My data is looking something like this:

| date_time | job_name | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2020 07:30:30 | job_1 | success |
| 01/01/2020 15:30:30 | job_1 | disabled |
| 01/01/2020 18:30:30 | job_1 | failed |
| 01/01/2020 08:30:30 | job_2 | success |
| 01/01/2020 18:30:30 | job_2 | disabled |
| 01/02/2020 15:30:30 | job_1 | success |
| 01/02/2020 08:30:30 | job_2 | success |
| 01/02/2020 18:30:30 | job_2 | success |

I am trying to group these data by the date (note, not the date/time) and job_name. Per date (note, not the date/time) I'd like to return whether a job was successful or not.

If one of the runs (or the only run) of a job on a day is "failed", my grouped row must return "failed" regardless of the other "status" results that day.

If one of the runs (or the only run) of a job on a day is "disabled", and there are no "failed" runs of that job that day, my grouped row must return "disabled".

If all of the runs of a job on a day are "success", my grouped row must return "success".

Hence, the expected result of my example table would be:

| date_time | job_name | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2020 | job_1 | failed |
| 01/01/2020 | job_2 | disabled |
| 01/02/2020 | job_1 | success |
| 01/02/2020 | job_2 | success |

I have tried to attain this result using a GROUP BY statement on the date_time and job_name columns but I can't manage to implement the logic of when to return the "success", "failed" and "disabled" status.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a combination of `GROUP BY` with `CASE` statements, and aggregate functions `COUNT` and `SUM`:

```sql
SELECT 
  CONVERT(DATE, date_time) AS date, --to extract only the date portion from the date_time column.
  job_name,
  CASE
    WHEN COUNT(*) = SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'failed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) THEN 'failed'
    WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'failed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN 'failed'
    WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'disabled' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN 'disabled'
    ELSE 'success'
  END AS status
FROM your_table
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, date_time), job_name;
```

[**dbfiddle DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/nV9z5tnz)

Here's an alternative with aggregate function `MAX`:

```sql
SELECT 
  CONVERT(DATE, date_time) AS date,
  job_name,
  CASE
    WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN status = 'failed' THEN 2 WHEN status = 'disabled' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 2 THEN 'failed'
    WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN status = 'disabled' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1 THEN 'disabled'
    ELSE 'success'
  END AS status
FROM your_table
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, date_time), job_name;
```

[**DBFiddle MAX DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/WFcijUH_)

Comment: How does this differ meaningfully from Tim Biegeleisen's answer?

Comment: This answer does not explicitly check that all records match `success`.  This may or not may be  a viable assumption.

Comment: Actually, I've used also the aggregate function `MAX`, check it out:

Answer (score 2):

Using conditional aggregation, we can try:

```sql
SELECT
    DATE(date_time) AS date_time,
    job_name,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'failed' THEN 1 END) > 0
         THEN 'failed'
         WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'disabled' THEN 1 END) > 0
         THEN 'disabled'
         WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN status != 'success' THEN 1 END) = 0
         THEN 'success' END AS status
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    DATE(date_time),
    job_name
ORDER BY
    DATE(date_time),
    job_name;
```

Comment: Shouldn't those be `SUM(CASE WHEN ... )` statements?  Won't you get a value for COUNT() even if the case statement yields NULL?

Comment: But you probably wouldn't have written it that way if you weren't confident, and you DO have 505K points.  :)

Comment: @AnnL. I prefer using `COUNT()` here rather than `SUM()` as the former avoids an `ELSE` expression.

Comment: Thanks, this and Xmehdi's answer worked!

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, here's another solution, one that uses PIVOT.  I can't predict which solution is likely to perform better: you'd have to experiment.

```
SELECT [date]
    ,  job_name
    ,  CASE 
          WHEN  [failed] > 0
          THEN  'failed'   
          WHEN  [disabled] > 0 and [failed] = 0
          THEN  'disabled'
          WHEN  [disabled] = 0 and [failed] = 0 and [success] > 0
          THEN  'success'
      END as status 
  FROM  (
      SELECT 
         CONVERT(DATE, date_time) as [date]
      ,  job_name
      ,  status
      from your_table
      ) as v
  PIVOT (COUNT(status) 
  FOR status IN (success, failed, disabled)) as c
ORDER BY 
       [date]
     , job_name
```

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hV4smyno) (based on the example one set up by XMedhi01)